# Can't use Vuex to display data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asp.net-core, vuex

I am a new .net+vuejs learner and i'm using
[this project template for vuejs](https://medium.com/js-dojo/template-vue-js-3-0-asp-net-core-5-0-visual-studio-2019-a18dd43b076b)

I'm trying to use vuex in my project to display countries data from database but it doesn't work

main.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

index.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import countries from "./module/countries/countries";

createApp(App).use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
modules: {
    countries: countries
}
});
```

store file

```
import axios from "axios";
const state = {
countries:[]
};


const countries = {
async getCountries({ commit }, payload) {
    const result = await axios.get("Pho/GetCountries");
    return result.data;
}
};

export default {
namespaced: true,
state,
mutations,
countries,
getters
}
```

my component

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import swal from 'sweetalert';
export default {
   
    name: "Home",
    data() {
        return {
            countries: [],
            
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getCountries: async function () {
            this.countries = await this.$store.dispatch("countries/getCountries");
        }
        },
    mounted() {
        this.getCountries();
    }
    }
    </script>
```

ERROR: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatch')
i tried to import store to my main.js like this

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './index.js'

createApp(App).use(router, store).mount('#app')
```

but the app doesn't ever lauch

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to call APIs from storage files. Use vuex storage for only storage, use mixins(recommended) or component methods for sending API. I will show a simple approach to managing vuex storage!
Storage File: `index.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
Vuex from 'vuex'
import router from '../router/index'
Vue.use(Vuex)
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: { 
    countries:[]
  },
  getters: {},
  mutations: {
      countriesChanger(state, payload) {
         state.countries = payload;
      },
  },
  actions: {},
});
```

Component File: `MyComponent.vue`

```
<template>
 <li v-for="country in countries">
   {{country}}
  </li>
</template>
<script>
export default {

name: "Home",
data() {
    return {
        countries: [],
        
    }
 },
 
  mounted() {
      this.getCountries(); // assume this function calls to your API
  },
  watch: {  
  "$store.state.countries": function () {
    // Listens when countries in storage updated
      this.countries = this.$store.state.countries;
    }
}
</script>
```

To change vuex storage item (to update countries) , use mutations  after getting data from your API:

```
this.$store.commit("countriesChanger", countriesFromAPI);
```

That's it!